# Remove reactions for a specific member from a specific message

Tags: discord.js

I want to remove member's reactions from specific messages when they leave the server for any reason. The below code is set up to work when someone sends a message, but that is just for testing, I will change that part later.

I first thought the code was deleting all the reactions found that its not removing all users, its removing the bots reactions, since they were the author of the post.

```
bot.channels.cache.get('786073099685593088').messages.fetch('842501905292066857').then((message) => {
    const userId = message.author.id
    const userReactions = message.reactions.cache.filter(reaction => reaction.users.cache.has(userId));
    try {
        for (const reaction of userReactions.values()) {
            reaction.users.remove(userId)
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

This one does nothing at all, but I tried to make the constant be outside so it wouldn't look at who authored the message the reactions are being removed from but rather who the author of the post that triggered the action (will later be changed to the member who left)

```
const author = message.author.id
bot.channels.cache.get('786073099685593088').messages.fetch('852625430950838302').then((message) => {
const userReactions = message.reactions.cache.filter(reaction => reaction.users.cache.has(author));
try {
    for (const reaction of userReactions.values()) {
        reaction.users.remove(author)
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my own issue with less code

```
bot.channels.cache.get('channelID').messages.fetch('messageID').then((message) => {
    message.reactions.cache.filter(reaction => reaction.users.remove(member.user.id));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Doing The Following And It May Fix Your Issue. This Will Remove The User(s) reactions.

```
reaction.users.remove(user.id)
```

Comment: userId is a const value that represents the message.author.id so my code already shows 'reaction.users.remove('11111111111111111') with the way my code is set up, user.id would return undefined.

Comment: then try reaction.user.id Instead.

Comment: I already figured out the solution below.